# Pandas - Get the value from the previous datetime minute for specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

## Get the value from the previous datetime minute per user

#### Original Dataframe

I have a Dataframe structured like this:

[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7lBX.jpg)

```
    User    Datetime    Hits
0   A   2021-03-10 15:25:26 10
1   A   2021-03-10 15:25:52 10
2   A   2021-03-10 15:26:09 12
3   A   2021-03-10 15:26:12 12
4   B   2021-03-10 15:25:32 6
5   A   2021-03-10 15:27:39 15
```

#### Goal

My goal is to obtain the **difference (Delta) per User between the current 'Hits' value and the value from last minute.**
For every specific datetime minute, the 'Hits' value per user is the same, as this value is the result from a value_counts() operation for this specific minute.
Hence, multiple similar 'Hits' values per user can be present per minute.

#### Methods tried

I have succeeded using .apply in combination with a rather complex function, but the problem is that this method is too slow for the size of the original dataframe.
More specifically **I am looking for a faster method**, ideally without custom functions.

#### Target Dataframe

My target Dataframe will look like this:

[Target Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2uo5.jpg)

```
User    Datetime    Hits    Delta
0   A   2021-03-10 15:25:26 10  <NA>
1   A   2021-03-10 15:25:52 10  <NA>
2   A   2021-03-10 15:26:09 12  2
3   A   2021-03-10 15:26:12 12  2
4   B   2021-03-10 15:25:32 6   <NA>
5   A   2021-03-10 15:27:39 15  3
```

#### Code for Dataframe

```
d = {'User': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','A'], 
     'Datetime': ['2021-03-10 15:25:26', '2021-03-10 15:25:52', '2021-03-10 15:26:09', '2021-03-10 15:26:12', '2021-03-10 15:25:32', '2021-03-10 15:27:39'], 
     'Hits': [10,10,12,12,6,15],
    'Delta': pd.NA}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this in a few small steps.

First we create a copy of your dataframe, called `df1` - we then `floor` the `Datetime` column to remove any seconds from the column so we can measure the changes in minutes.

We then apply a series of conditional checks to apply your delta calculation.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df.copy() 
## might be better to only copy the columns you're interested in for memory.
df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'])
df1['Datetime'] = df1['Datetime'].dt.floor('T')

con = df1.sort_values(['User','Datetime'])\
         .groupby('User')['Datetime'].diff() >= pd.Timedelta('1 min')


df.loc[con,'delta'] = df.groupby('User')['Hits'].diff()
df['delta'] = df.groupby([df1['User'], df1['Datetime']])['delta'].ffill()
```

---

```
print(df)
  User             Datetime  Hits  delta
0    A  2021-03-10-15:25:26    10    NaN
1    A  2021-03-10-15:25:52    10    NaN
2    A  2021-03-10-15:26:09    12    2.0
3    A  2021-03-10-15:26:12    12    2.0
4    B  2021-03-10-15:25:32     6    NaN
5    A  2021-03-10-15:27:39    15    3.0
```

Comment: Great solution; it brings the calculation time way down and solves the computation time challenge. Thanks.

Comment: @Reno many thanks for accepting the answer, I wasn't sure how it would perform on your larger dataset, but I hope it works out as expected. Great first question btw